# Order of nesting between Auth0Provider and (Browser)Router in React

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have something about Auth0 integration with React that I wasn't able to find an answer on official forums -

The SDK docs/samples mention that `Auth0Provider` should wrap the React `Router` element
(https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#1-protecting-a-route-in-a-react-router-dom-app):

```
    <Auth0Provider
      domain="YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN"
      clientId="YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {/* Don't forget to add the history to your router */}
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Auth0Provider>
```

This forces us (the SDK users) to create `history` object manually and then pass it to both `Auth0Provider` and to the `Router`, so that we'll be able to manipulate the same version of history on authentication redirects (again, as explained in the docs).

It seems to be possible to reverse the order of nesting, having `Auth0Provider` wrapped by the default `BrowserRouter`. This allows us to create custom wrapper over `Auth0Provider` with access to the built-in history object via `useHistory` hook:

```
export const AppAuthentication: React.FC = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState: AppState) => {
    history.replace(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={...}
      clientId={...}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

The usage is simpler now -

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AppAuthentication>
         ....
      </AppAuthentication>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I've did some quick testing, and it seems to be working fine. Is there a reason **not** to follow this approach? It seems to be much cleaner than maintaining own history copy as recommended by the official guide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got a word from Auth0 that this approach is fine, but unfortunately I have nothing official from them (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this is an old post, but to answer the last question: You might need access to the auth0 hooks if you want to change routing at the Router level.

**LoginCheckRoute.jsx**

```
const LoginCheckRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        return isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

**App.js**

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/login" component={MyLoginForm} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/onlyAuthorizedAllowedHere/" component={MyComponent} />
</Router>
```

That being said there should be other ways to achieve the "redirect to login page" flow even with the order you mentioned

**App.js**

```
<Router>
  <AppAuthentication>
     ....
  </AppAuthentication>
</Router>
```

**MainLayout.jsx**

```
const MainLayout = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  return (
    { isAuthenticated ? <LoginPage> : <Outlet> }
  );
}
```